# Dynamic objects or properties?

Tags: vb.net

I apologize for the vague question, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

What I need is something that works like a class object with various fields and properties for storing data. 
But, since not all the fields/properties are known at the compile time, I also need to be able to add and use new fields/properties in runtime.

These objects would later be arranged in lists, sorted by the values in those fields/properties and bound to WPF controls.

For now I'm using just that: class objects with various properties, but I'm starting to run into problems, where I need to add more fields/properties.

Is there something I could use to achieve this in vb.net?

Edit:

Ok, I'll try to illustrate.

Currently I have something like this. 
Let's say I have defined an object like this

```
Public Class DataEntry
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Msc As Integer
End Class
```

That works fine if I know all the properties I will have at the start. I run into problems if I suddenly need to add another property:

```
Public Class DataEntry
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Msc As Integer
    Public Property AdditionalDescription As String
End Class
```

Of course, I could recompile the whole thing, but since I don't know all the possible properties I will be needing in the end, I was wondering, maybe there is a way to achieve this from runtime?

Or should I just use complicated heap of arrays instead of custom objects?

Comment: you want to create dynamic object in VB.net?

Comment: _"I apologize for the vague question"_ no need to apologize, but you could try to post a little less vague question. What are you actually trying to achieve? Post what you have tried. Why are the fields and properties unkown at compile time?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok, I added additional description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to add new properties to a class during run time.

If you don't want to add properties to the class ahead of time which you might not use, then you could instead use a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store 'properties' which you're not aware of until run time.

```
Public Property RunTimeProperties As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
```

A dictionary which holds values of type 'Object' can store just about anything. Strings, Arrays, Lists etc.

```
RunTimeProperties.Add("Length", 100)
RunTimeProperties.Add("Height", 200)
RunTimeProperties.Add("MiddleName", "Rupert")
RunTimeProperties.Add("SiblingsNames", New String() {"John", "Sarah", "Michael"})
```

You can use the [TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the values out of the dictionary.

```
Dim value As Object

If RunTimeProperties.TryGetValue("Length", value) Then
    ' Length was found in the dictionary
Else
    ' Length was not found in the dictionary
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Now if I add these dictionaries to a list, can I sort the list based on the values of a specific key stored in dictionary? For example `MyList = MyList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Item("MiddleName"))` doesn't really work.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, my bad. What I needed was: `MyList = MyList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Item("MiddleName")).ToList`
Thanks for the help!