# Adding methods/properties at runtime from data?

Tags: .net, vb.net

One of our customers has asked us if we could add another field to one of our classes. The field would really only be useful for them, and, obviously, we'd rather not have a custom version just for them.

The obvious solution to this problem is to have our base class have a `Dictionary` called `Extras` and put anything we want in there. But there is a problem - the customers access our objects using (primarily) use `public property X`.

I know I can add new methods and properties to .net classes, but is there a way to do this at runtime *from data*? For instance, if a particular object's `Extras` has an entry called "SomeField", can I add a new property called `SomeField` at runtime?

Comment: The customer could create an extension method on his end to reference extras field in the way he's comfortable with.

Comment: It seems like the easiest, most cost effective thing would be to just add the property. It doesnt cost anything to provide it even of no one else needs it.  Adding something like a Dictionary to expose this (and future) special thing means a breaking change if/when the item gains widespread appeal and gets "promoted" to a regular property.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible according to similar questions on this site and elsewhere.  For example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28937027/5162073.

Comment: Thanks @BrianMStafford. I asked because this is something we do all the time on the iOS side, so I was wondering if I was just missing something on the .net side.

Comment: What good would adding a field/method at runtime do you? since nothing could be compiled against it, I don't see how it could be _used_.  If you want to add properties dynamically, say to a report, there are probably other ways to solve that problem. Can you be more specific as to exactly what they_re trying to _use_ the new fields for?

Comment: @DStanley - Option Strict Off. Use a dynamic (late-bound) object and you can call any method you want. If it's not there, trap the resulting error.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz If that's the use case, then have your objects implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` and add runtime support for properties it does not know about at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple ways to solve the problem; none involve adding a property at runtime, which is not possible afaik.

**1. Explicit interface implementation**

It sounds like you don't provide a public interface for your classes (you should). If you do, you can compile the class once, and instruct different customers to use different interfaces.

```
Public Interface IClass
    Property X As String
End Interface

Public Interface ICustomer1
    Inherits IClass
    Property Y As String
End Interface

Public Class A
    Implements IClass, ICustomer1

    Public Property X As String Implements IClass.X

    Public Property Y As String Implements ICustomer1.Y

End Class

Module MyApplication

    Sub Main()
        Dim c As IClass = New A()
        Dim c1 As ICustomer1 = New A()
        c.X = "x"
        c.Y = "y" ' compile error, 'Y' is not a member of 'IClass'.
        c1.X = "x"
        c1.Y = "y"
    End Sub

End Module
```

It would technically allow all customers to use ICustomer1, because it is a public interface. Note: `Dim c = New A()` is still possible here, so you may also want to provide a factory which creates instances of A as a specific interface.

**2. Setting the property's `EditorBrowsable` attribute to Never**

This is sneaky, as it will hide the property Y from the customer, but it will still be accessible. It makes it a bit inconvenient since it won't show up in intellisense. But you can just let your customer know it exists and they will be able to use it. Note: it becomes non-browsable only when referencing the dll - not when it is referenced in another project in Visual Studio

```
Public Class A
    Public Property X As String

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Property Y As String

End Class
```

I hope one of these can help.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand this - we would export one interface for one set of people and another for the rest? I'll think on that one...

Comment: You can. But if you are to achieve this by compiling differently for different customers, you might as well compile with and without the property. [Compiler Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/directives) could help here... My example just exposes all interfaces to all customers and you would need to instruct each customer which interface to use. You would not be able to provide a subset of interfaces to different customers on account of `Public Class A    Implements IClass, ICustomer1` requiring that they are all available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `Property`:

```
Class MyObject
  Public Property Extras(customFieldName As String) As String
    Get
      'return custom field value here based on customfieldname (e.g. sql query)        
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      'set custom field value here based on customfieldname (e.g. sql insert)        
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

If you want intellisense, you will need to provide a list of options to the customer. You can send your customers a shared class:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ExtraFields
  Public Shared Property MyExtraFieldName1 As String = "MyExtraFieldName1"
  Public Shared Property MyExtraFieldName2 As String = "MyExtraFieldName2"

  Private Sub New()
    'private constructor to prevent instantiation
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then your customers use it as follows:

```
Dim o As New MyObject
Dim s As String = o.Extras(ExtraFields.MyExtraFieldName1)
```

Your base code only sees the custom fieldname as a `String`, so you can use the same code for all customers. Each customer has an individualised `ExtraFields` class which contains their particular custom fieldnames.

If the customer is allowed to create new fieldnames, then they just hand them as `String` values to the property, and it is up to them to spell them correctly:

```
o.Extras("UserDefinedFieldName1") = "foo"
```